# Magento 2 How to order categories by entity id?

Tags: magento2, category, orders

I get store categories from category helper, i need to order categories by entity id with my array.
Here is my code

```
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,

...

$this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;

public function getStoreCategories($sorted = true, $asCollection = true, $toLoad = true)
{
 
    $order = array(2,6,3,4,5);


    $menuitems = $this->_categoryHelper
                ->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad) 
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $order)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq' => 1));
     
    return $menuitems;
}
```

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the MySQL `FIELD()` expression to your collection:

```
$menuitems->getSelect()
    ->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $order).')'));
```